# Use of mysql_unbuffered_query in Zend Frame Work, is it supported?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I need to run a query which will retrieve a huge amount of records.
This means I can't use the ZF wrappers for mysqli, which deep below the hood uses mysqli-store-result.
So, is there a wrapper in ZF for using the mysqli mysqli-use-result [link text](https://www.php.net/mysqli_use_result), which will return an Iterator/record-set/resource and not the array with all the results already loaded into the memory, Or do I need to implement it myself?

Comment: Why can't you use the ZF wrappers?

Comment: I can't as the read the entire set into memory before returning it.
Which will cause the process to crash due to lack of memory (I am talking here millions of records). I will use a ZF wrapper which I am going to extend from the mysqli wrapper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, no Zend Framework database adapters make use of [ext/mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php).  There are adapters for [ext/mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [ext/pdo_mysql](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

In the MySQLi adapter, it always calls [`mysqli_store_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) (see Zend/Db/Statement/Mysqli.php, near line 250), which means it only supports **buffered** query results.  Zend Framework does not currently support any option to change this, so you could try to edit that line of code yourself to use `mysqli_use_result()`.

**edit:** In the PDO_MySQL adapter, the default is to use **buffered** queries.

PHP 5.4.6 source, file ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c, line 590, in function pdo_mysql_handle_factory():

```
H->buffered = H->emulate_prepare = 1;
```

Note that regardless of using unbuffered queries, if you call `fetchAll()` on a database wrapper class, you'll fetch all rows of your huge result set, and probably exceed PHP's memory limit.  So instead, you must begin a query and write a loop to fetch rows one at a time.